# X.509 using fingerprint to validate key chain

Tags: java, x509certificate

I have a project where I have to validate a given Certificate's chain, so that all its authorities are in my persistence.

I was told that if I retrieve the thumbprint of a given certificate, I could use it to identify its CA's. Is this true and if yes how (most likely in JAVA) can I do this?

We already figured out how to use javas build in to retrieve a thumbprint, but no one could tell me how to identify CA or the chain with the thumbprint of a single certificate yet. Maybe there's a different way to obtain my goal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was told that if I retrieve the thumbprint of a given certificate, I could use it to identify its CA's. Is this true and if yes how (most likely in JAVA) can I do this?

No, it is false. The certificate thumbprint is a hash calculated on the entire certificate. The thumbprint does not contain information about the CA

> We already figured out how to use javas build in to retrieve a thumbprint, but no one could tell me how to identify CA or the chain with the thumbprint of a single certificate yet. Maybe there's a different way to obtain my goal ?

You can check if the certificate is signed with the private key of the issuing certificate, verifying the digital signature with the public key associated with the issuer

In java, check this with your list of trusted certificates

```
 Certificate certificate = ... //Last certificate from bottom to top of the provided chain
 Certificate issuerCertificate =... //one of the certificates of the trusted list
 certificate.verify(issuerCertificate.getPublicKey());
```

Comment: Hey, yeah i figured that out by now but im not able to create a certifiicate of type java.security.cert.Certificate. :S

Comment: I recommend editing the question to add the code you are using and the trace of the errors, otherwise I can not help you to fix the issue

Comment: already solved it. I have to use a CertificateFactory and a ByteArrayInputStream to generate the certificate as a X509Certificate (explicitly casted) (for certificates the getBytes as UTF-8 encoding) so i can use all methods on my certificate. Thanks for your answer